# Moving and Installing a Cast Iron Bathtub

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, cast-iron

I am renovating my bathroom. My wife really wants a cast iron bathtub due to its durability. The one she wants weighs approximately 350 lbs. Does anyone have any practical installation tips for managing the weight?

Comment: Are you sure the floor can support that weight (plus the weight of the water and anyone in said tub)?

Comment: Not sure yet , I am still demoing it and wanted to check the structures after I pull the tub

Comment: Years ago I purchased a good quality steel tub to replace original builder's grade steel tub.  I was worried about the weight of a cast iron tub. Later we had a plumber install a cast iron tub in a rental property. The plumbers handled the cast iron tub easily and it has a better appearance than the steel tub we had installed in our house. If I had to do it again I would choose cast iron.

Comment: Are you thinking of a clawfoot tub or just a regular tub that happens to be cast iron? If it's the clawfoot option, all you really need to think about is making sure that the point loads are taken care of. (A couple hundred extra pounds is pretty trivial in the world of tubs that can hold 1000# of water...)

Comment: No it's going to be a skirted alcove model.